# Create ADO.NET DataView showing only selected Columns

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataview, datacolumn

In C# & .NET, can one create a `DataView` that includes only a *proper* subset of the `DataColumn`s of a given `DataTable`?

In terms of relational algebra, one assigns a `RowFilter` in order to perform a "selection" operation (σ).  How would one perform a "projection" operation (π)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't do that, but you can create a copy of the table with only the columns you want :

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable table2 = view.ToTable(false, "FirstColumn", "SecondColumn", "ThirdColumn");
```

Optionally you can return rows that have distinct values for the selected columns :

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable table2 = view.ToTable(true, "FirstColumn", "SecondColumn", "ThirdColumn");
```

Comment: Thank you, Thomas.  I'd also like to be able to include calculated columns in "table2".  For example, view.ToTable ( "FirstColumn * 2", "SecondColumn > 0", "TRIM(ThirdColumn)" ) .

Comment: create them in table and select them in ToTable, or add them to table2 after you created it...

Comment: You can shorten this by using the DefaultView of the DataTabe: `$DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable("FirstColumn", "SecondColumn", "ThirdColumn");`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque how do I add a condition like `FirstColumn = 'comevalue'`?

Comment: @Smith you can add it when you create the view: `new DataView(table) { RowFilter = "FirstColumn = 'somevalue'" }` (or something like that)

Answer (score 1):

Well I can't see any reason for "wanting" to do that... Remember, a DataView is just a list of pointers to the rows in the original table, and there is obviously no way to remove columns from the the original table... at least not without affecting every other function utilizing that table... Just only use the columns you want...

Answer (score 0):

create dataview as a swap from one table to other table, and use the dtswap as datasource.

```
DataView dw = new DataView(dtfee);
            DataTable dtswap = new DataTable();
            dtswap = dw.ToTable(true,"Fees", "FeeAmount", "Year", "CollectorName", "Month");
```

Answer (score -1):

`DataSet` and its associated types have no ability to perform relational operations.