# How Create linq query select dynamic custom fileds

Tags: c#, linq

I want to reformat the data without going back to the database and in a dynamic way
So that the user can specify what columns he wants to collect

how I can
Write an sql string and execute it like EXECUTE IMMEDIAT in Oracle
Inside C# Linq
want to do a lock like combining two or more fields (multiply - merge...)
ToTable
It only allows me to specify the names of existing fields

```
FillDataSorce(params P)
{
  
  // p It is a variable containing the field to be queried
//Like

//field1 = d["field1"] ,
//field2 = d["field2"] ,
//field sum = d["field1"] +d["field2"]
 
 BSo.DataSource = from d in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    select new 
                    {
                       P.Select(p => p) //col3col2 = d["col1"] + d["col2"] Dynamic field example
                       
                    };
}
```

Comment: Your second code snippet isn't valid code, which never helps in asking a clear question. If I understand correctly, you have a data table of which you want to show columns the user can select. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13760072/861716) is a duplicate.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example you showed I know, but it is not what I want because I want to do a lock like combining two or more fields (multiply - merge...)
I want a sentence
ToTable
It only allows me to specify the names of existing fields

Comment: Still not clear what you want. What is `classP`?  Maybe you should show sample data and an output as you figure it should look like.

Comment: classP 
Array of a class containing the statement of the fields {name - field or fields and the operation between them} that I want to query

Comment: Without knowing what `classP` is and how it is to be used, it is hard to answer. Provide more details. Consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

Comment: There is no classp significance

The important thing is how I can query the query in a dynamic way
There is no in
LINQKit
I don't want static fields for the query