# Extracting Specific Columns from a DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have some code in my C# application which extracts data from a SQL database.

This `DataTable` is used in various places throughout my application, and is displayed in multiple `DataGridViews`.

However, I want to show only some of the columns in the `Datatable`, not all of them.

Also the columns I want to display are different in each of the `DataGridViews`.

e.g.

- Show Columns 1-3 in DataGridView1
- Show Columns 4-6 in DataGridView2
- Show Columns 7-12 in DataGridView3

etc

I could of course just write different code to extract the required fields from SQL for each of the `DataGridViews`, but this doesn't seem like a very concise solution.

It would be better (I think) if I could use the one `DataTable` extracted from SQL, and apply multiple filters to it in the application for displaying different Columns in each of the `DataGridViews`.

I looked at using `DataView` but whilst this has a `Sort` method, it doesn't seem to have a `Filter` method

e.g.

```
DataTable table = GetDateFromSql();
DataView view = new DataView(table);
view.Sort = "FieldName";
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like -

```
view.Filter = "SELECT cola, colB, colC";
myDataGridView.DataSource = view;
```

I know there is a `RowFilter` method, but in effect, its the Columns I want to filter.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Similar Question:
[Showing only selected column in dataview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201255/create-ado-net-dataview-showing-only-selected-columns)

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable table2 = view.ToTable(false, "FirstColumn", "SecondColumn", "ThirdColumn");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set DataGridViewColumn property visible to false, if You dont care about the data in that column. In asp.net web forms You can get the column by its name.